# How to connect two wireless networks to share internet?

Tags: networking, openwrt

I have 2 devices:

- Device A: Huawei E8231 emits wifi signal
- Device B: Ravpower WD-02 device emits wifi signal
- Device A has access to internet and is running stock firmware.
- Device B doesn't have access to internet and is running Openwrt Attitude Adjustment

I want device B to connect to A, wirelessly. So that when I connect to device B's wifi through computer or phone, I can access internet seamlessly. Just the way chromecast device's wifinetwork can easily join another wifi network for internet given SSID and password.

I have already looked up the option of WDS, which I think my device A doesn't support even if my device B supports it (as client).

Any other way I can go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having a similar situation: the answer is to make device A a Client of Device B.

**Step 0:** Open Openwrt login page on device B.

**Step 1:** Click on "join" and join the wifi network which which has internet. Make sure the network you check is 'lan'.

**Step 2:** Add new wifi interface. This is the signal you will connect to from your devices. Make sure the network checked is 'wan'.

**Step 3:** Go to Network>Interfaces> click on edit for 'wan' and under Physical settings and uncheck "Bridge" option.

and you should have your device B connecting to device A for internet wirelessly! :) Make sure router pages of either devices are not set to same location. That is to say, if one device is using 192.168.1.1 then make the other use something else.